# How to get json object value

Tags: php, json

i have json return object value is like this:

```
{
"statuses": [
    {
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent",
            "iso_language_code": "en"
        },
        "created_at": "Sun Jun 08 20:46:44 +0000 2014",
        "id": 475740733211947008,
        "id_str": "475740733211947008",
        "text": "RT @XMenMovies: #JenniferLawrence brings the many shapes of #Mystique to life in #XMen: Days of Future Past. http:\/\/t.co\/cIpp5lGdDH http:\/\/\u2026",
        "source": "Twitter for Mac<\/a>",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null
    }
]
```

}

And i am using the values in array like this:data.statuses  and i have another json return value like this:

```
{
"0": [
    {
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent",
            "iso_language_code": "en"
        },
        "created_at": "Sun Jun 08 20:46:44 +0000 2014",
        "id": 475740733211947000,
        "id_str": "475740733211947008",
        "text": "RT @XMenMovies: #JenniferLawrence brings the many shapes of #Mystique to life in #XMen: Days of Future Past. http://t.co/cIpp5lGdDH http://…",
        "source": "Twitter for Mac</a>",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null
    }
]
```

}

I have '0' instead of any name. How to get this value?

Comment: `data.statuses` is not valid PHP (*edit:* It's valid, but it doesn't access the `status` field of `data`). Please show how you parse the JSON.

Comment: You have to decode it with `json_decode()` and then change the key and then encode it with `json_encode()`

Comment: Actually i am getting these values in js file like this if (JQTWEET.search) data = data.statuses; var count = data[i].retweet_count in for loop.and append the div.

Comment: So, the question is about JavaScript, not PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :) thank me later!

```
$jsonData = '{ "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" }';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpArray);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
}
```

Comment: You have to pass `true` as secondary param to json_decode to get array instead of object. Thank me later!

Comment: Hope it is late enough, THANKS!